# Android base flavor without duplicate class error

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I have few versions of my app: common version, say `mainapp` and few builds specific per customer, say `custom1`, `custom2`, `custom3`. 
And I want to have base flavor for all customX flavors.

I was trying to do like this:

Create project structure:

```
app\src\main
app\src\mainapp
app\src\commonflavor
app\src\custom3
```

And config:

```
productFlavors {
    mainapp {
    }
    custom1 {
    }
    custom2 {
    }
    custom3 {
    }
}

sourceSets {
    custom1 {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/commonflavor/java']
    }
    custom2 {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/commonflavor/java']
    }
    custom3 {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/commonflavor/java', 'src/custom3/java']
    }
}
```

In `commonflavor` I put common java classes for all customX flavors, say `MainActivity.java` and `SecondActivity.java`. But in `custom3` I need separate `SecondActivity.java`.

In this case I have an error `error: duplicate class: SecondActivity` from `src/commonflavor/java` and `src/custom3/java`.

For now I have resolved this using class dupllication:

```
sourceSets {
    custom1 {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/commonflavor/java']
    }
    custom2 {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/commonflavor/java']
    }
    custom3 {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/custom3/java']
    }
}
```

I have copied `src/commonflavor/java` from srcDirs and copy `MainActivity.java` to `custom3`. The problem is that I have 2 clone of `MainActivity.java` file in `src/commonflavor/java` and `src/custom3/java`

How to resolve this situation without code duplication?

Comment: I suspect that there's no need for the `commonflavor` source set. Those files could very well just stay under `src/main` and be inherited by default by all the flavors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution what I founded is write all classes in app\src\main and add where needed:

```
if(BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("mainapp")) {
  // mainapp code
} else {
  // coomon flavor code
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit apprehensive about this approach because the apk could possibly be decompiled and the `FLAVOR` changed to `pro` easily.

Comment: But wont this increase your apk size since it contains all the files, but when you use flavour type build, your unwanted flavour filed will not be compiled and your apk size reduces.